# How to grab all but the last part of a string with regex and .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a URL that looks like this...

```
https://www.example.com/IMG/YyXn5/XPATH/home/logoXEXT.jpg
```

or

```
https://www.example.com/IMG/YyXn5/XPATH/home/logo
```

The XEXT.jpg may or may not appear

My current htaccess rule is ...

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%{HTTP_HOST} ^/IMG/(.*)/XPATH/home/(.*)(XEXT.*?)?:(.*) [NC]
```

but for some reason the XEXT.jpg is part of %2, I want it to be part of %3 such that %3 will either be empty or it will be XEXT.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition with a lazy quantifier:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%{HTTP_HOST} ^/IMG/(.*)/XPATH/home/(.*?)(XEXT\.[^:]+)?:(.*) [NC]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/87GmWJ/1)

Comment: @Terry: Did this help?